# Relation and difference between recursively enumerable languages and Turing complete languages?

Tags: programming-languages, computer-science, theory

From https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursively_enumerable_language

> **a formal language** is called **recursively enumerable** (also
>   recognizable, partially decidable, semidecidable, Turing-acceptable or
>   Turing-recognizable) if it is a recursively enumerable subset in the
>   set of all possible words over the alphabet of the language, i.e., if
>   there exists a Turing machine which will enumerate all valid strings
>   of the language.

From https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_completeness

> a system of data-manipulation rules (such as a computer's instruction
>   set, **a programming language**, or a cellular automaton) is said to
>   be **Turing complete** or computationally universal if it can be used
>   to simulate any single-taped Turing machine.

So both recursively enumerable languages and Turing complete languages are defined in terms of Turing Machines.

1. What are the fundamental differences between recursively enumerable
   languages and Turing complete languages?

   For example, is it correct that

   - a recursively enumerable language a set of inputs to a Turing Machine for it to recognize, while
   - a Turing complete language is the language provided by a Turing Machine or its equivalent?

   So do the two concepts belong to two unrelated aspects of Turing machines?
2. What are their relations?

   For a language,

   - does being recursively enumerable imply being Turing complete?
   - Does being Turing complete imply being recursively enumerable?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Your confusion stems from overloaded terminology. The word "language" in "Turing complete languages" refers to a programming language, while in "recursively enumerable language", it refers to a [formal language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_language) - that is, a set of strings formed over some alphabet.

So you're correct when you state:

> the two concepts belong to two unrelated aspects of Turing machines

Both use Turing machines in their definition (at least in the most oft-used definition), but they are not the same class of mathematical object. This should clear up (2) for.

To clear up your other questions:

> a recursively enumerable language a set of inputs to a Turing Machine for it to recognize

Yes, in fact, the recursively enumerable languages are also known as the Turing-recognizable languages. They are a strict *superset* of the decidable languages. For example, the halting problem is recognizable, but infamously undecidable.

> a Turing complete language is the language provided by a Turing Machine or its equivalent?

Formally(-ish), a Turing complete language is one that can compute the same set of number-theoretic functions (i.e. functions *N^k -> N*) as a Turing machine.

Also, in the future, please try to ask one question per post. Thank you